# PatternSyntaxException in java

Tags: java, android, patternsyntaxexception

i am trying to replace the below with ""(Null)

```
java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error U_REGEX_BAD_INTERVAL near index 50:

01-05 14:11:14.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1546): FATAL EXCEPTION: main
01-05 14:11:14.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1546): java.util.regex.PatternSyntaxException: Syntax error U_REGEX_BAD_INTERVAL near index 50:
01-05 14:11:14.660: E/AndroidRuntime(1546): <html><head>  <style type="text/css">@font-face { font-family: MyCustomFont;  src: url("file:///android_asset/fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.otf") }body { font-family: MyCustomFont; font-size:14.0pt; text-align: center;vertical-align:middle;line-height: normal;} </style> </head><body>
```

i am geting this error what is the problem here?

**EDIT**

this is my code

`"a"` contains the value with tags

```
<html><head>  <style type="text/css">@font-face { font-family: MyCustomFont;  src: 
url("file:///android_asset/fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.otf") }body { font-family:MyCustomFont;
 font-size:14.0pt; text-align: center;vertical-align:middle;line-height: normal;}    </style>
</head><body>365<i>xy</i></body></html>


val =<html><head>  <style type=\"text/css\">"
        + "@font-face { font-family: MyCustomFont;  src: url(\"file:///android_asset/fonts/MyriadPro-Regular.otf\") }"
        + "body { font-family: MyCustomFont; font-size:"14.0pt"; text-align: center;vertical-align:middle;line-height: normal;}</style></head><body>
a.getText().replaceAll(val, "")
```

Comment: Are you using that html as a regex or something?

Comment: i am just trying to replace the above tags with null so that i get the exact length of text

Comment: What is `Constants.HTML_PREFIX_IPHONE`?

Comment: You need to escape characters with special meaning in the regex

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
a.getText().replaceAll(java.util.regex.Pattern.quote(val), "")
```

This will quote special characters in your pattern.

Btw. this is a very fragile way to remove the header. If the header is changed just a little bit it will no longer be removed.

Comment: yes it works fine but its not escaping the tags, i want the text size of the content within the tags so now its giving the total height including tags..